# How do run VSCode debugger with a dotnet app that uses command line options?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-3.1, vscode-debugger

When opening the app normally through the terminal and not trying to use the VSCode Debugger, I'd just type this into my gitbash terminal:

```
$ dotnet run --project ProjectName -option stuff -option2 otherStuff
```

I can debug fine on projects that don't have command line options, but I can't figure out how to make the debugger recognize and open the project using those options (which I called "option" and "option2" here).

Answer (score 1):

To launch the .NET debugger in VSCode (assuming you added the default assets to build) VSCode will look inside of the .vscode folder for a launch.json file. Inside of that file you're looking for an "args": [], array to add your command line arguments to.

See the [VSCode documentation on launch.json attributes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) for more information.